# Looking for best solution to implement AJAX TreeGrid

Tags: javascript, ajax, treeview, dhtml

I'm looking for a Ajax/TreeGrid (Tree with multiple columns) implementation.

It has to:

1. support server side sorting
2. support on demand leaf loading - only children of open nodes are loaded
3. support paging - nodes have to be loaded in chunks, only visible records are requested from server
4. be free to use in commercial project

I tried Dojo (dojox.grid.LazyTreeGrid) and it seems to have problems with pagination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ExtJS's TreeGrid](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel) meets all your criteria except for the last one. Our implementation uses server-side sorting and on-demand loading/creating/deleting/moving of child nodes on the client, and then we push that data back to the server for persistance.

Ext is a huge framework, but you can take advantage of their dynamic loading to keep your page load times short.

You can download it for free to see if it's a good fit and perhaps decide if it's worth licensing.

Comment: +1 for ExtJS, very solid framework with good support and a great userbase

Answer (score 7):

I'd try http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxTreeGrid/index.shtml

It is not free, but it's only $299, which is not much for a commercial project. You probably have better support and more guaranteed updates. Good support on a component like this will repay itself quickly.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this [dhtmlx tree](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxTreeGrid/index.shtml). 
Not sure if it provides sever side sorting feature.